# How to initialize generic object in .NET

Tags: vb.net

I have 3 different classes - pencil, pen, and book.

There's a generic object, called obj, that can store any of those 3 classes.

How do I initialize the generic object?

For example, normally it would be:

```
Dim purplePencil as Pencil
purplePencil = New Pencil
```

Now, I'm doing this:

```
Dim obj as Object
Dim purplePencil as Pencil
obj = purplePencil
obj = New Pencil
```

However, I don't know if obj is either a Pencil, Pen, or Book.

So, is there a way to initialize obj, without knowing the exact class type?

Comment: Why do you need obj to be of type Object? Can we get some context of what you are trying to do?

Comment: obj needs to be generic enough to store a type of Pencil, Pen, or Book. Basically, I don't know what class obj is, but need a way to initialize whatever class type it is

Comment: doing `Dim obj = new Pencil()` or `Dim obj = new Book()` is fine

Comment: I don't know if obj is a Pencil or a Book

Comment: When you say initialize you mean how to set properties on the Pencil or book?

Comment: `So, is there a way to initialize obj, without knowing the exact class type?` You can create an object via refelction, e.g. [Activator.CreateInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=net-5.0). In this case you can pass the object type by string.

Comment: I would recommend reading up on factories, since a factory is likely to be what you want.  There are a variety of ways to do this; the simplest is to have a `Select Case` block where you set `obj` to `New Pencil`, `New Pen`, or `New Book` depending on (whatever it is you use to decide whether you want a new pencil, pen, or book).

Comment: Do classes `Book`, `Pen` and `Pencil` have _any_ common traits or properties (or functionality)? If not, then they probably shouldn't have any class commonality either I would say. But if they _do_, then another option is to use an Interface, `IItem`, for example, to provide a pattern of appearance/behavior. `IItem` might, for example, provide `Color`, `Price`, `Owner`, etc Properties. Eg `Dim obj As IItem = New Pencil`. But I don't really know why you wouldn't just say `Dim aPencil As IItem = New Pencil`. You need to explain a bit more as to the 'whys', I think.

Comment: hpnmoater5554: 1) @Craig 's suggestion to use a `Select Case` may be what you want to use for right now.  `Select Case` is simple, it lets you change between `Pencil`, `Pen`, and `Book`, and while factories are good, they are more advanced.  You should probably just use `Select Case` for now, then look at factories at a later time.  2) The language you're using is VB.NET, but it's different from .NET.  .NET is a system, and VB.NET is a specific language that's basically related to that system.  ...

Comment: ... 3) "Generic" means something a little bit different.  You're using it right in the normal English sense, but in programming, "generic" has a special meaning.  4) First try using `Select Case` to solve this problem and see if that's all you need.  Then after you've spent more time and had some more practice, research generics.  Then after you've spent even more time and had more practice, research factories.  First though, just try using `Select Case`.  When you're ready, move on to generics before moving on to factories.  (Also, study interfaces before moving on to factories.)

Comment: Thank you for all of your help! Alex B's suggestion of using Activator.CreateInstance was actually what I was looking for. Thanks to everyone who posted - using the "Select Case" option would have also sufficed too, I just realized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more specifics an answer is difficult.  You might be looking for [inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/objects-and-classes/inheritance-basics).  A very simple example.

First the classes

```
Public MustInherit Class BaseClass

End Class

Public Class pencil
    Inherits BaseClass

End Class

Public Class pen
    Inherits BaseClass

End Class

Public Class book
    Inherits BaseClass

End Class

Public Class obj
    Private someClass As BaseClass

    Public Sub New(whBase As BaseClass)
        Me.someClass = whBase
    End Sub

    Public Function WhBase() As String
        Return Me.someClass.GetType.Name
    End Function
End Class
```

Then in use

```
    Dim ob As New obj(New pen)
    Debug.WriteLine(ob.WhBase)
    ob = New obj(New book)
    Debug.WriteLine(ob.WhBase)
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write out the code, so I selected this as the correct answer. Alex B's method of using Activator.CreateInstance was also very helpful as well!